# Control cellphone camera via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, nokia, n73

I'd like to be able to control the Photo and Video camera functions of a Nokia N73 cellphone remotely using Bluetooth, in C#.

I've seen the [32feet.NET Bluetooth Library](http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx) but really I've no idea what to do with it. Any existing [Bluetooth profile](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/Bluetooth%20Profiles%20and%2032feet.NET.html) that is **specifically designed to control camera**-functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a [**Basic Imaging Profile** (BIP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVRCP#Basic_Imaging_Profile_.28BIP.29), of which a subset **Remote Camera** function allows the initiator *(PC)* to remotely use a digital camera *(on the Cellphone)*

Also, the [Toshiba Bluetooth Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack#Toshiba_stack) for Windows has a:

- "Remote Camera" tool for Bluetooth Cameras with "RemCam"-profile
  support, which is a (not mandatory) sub-profile of the BIP-profile.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, most of the mobiles in the market does not support "Remote camera" functionality of the BIP profile. They just use BIP to send and receieve images.